# How can I make an object in box2dlights unaffected by light?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

When i create an object in libgdx and Box2D it is automatically affected by light and it is casting shadows. Is there a way to make an object that does not cast shadows?

Comment: Have you managed this to work? I have the same issue, and have problem seeting the filters mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shadows happen when a `Light` ray collides with a `Fixture`. This collision handling is done via standard box2d queries and it uses the box2d `Filter`. See [the code here](https://github.com/libgdx/box2dlights/blob/master/src/box2dLight/Light.java#L361).

You can set your filter bits via the following method found in `Light`:

```
/**
* create new contact filter for ALL LIGHTS with give parameters
*/
static public void setContactFilter(short categoryBits, short groupIndex,
            short maskBits) {
    filterA = new Filter();
    filterA.categoryBits = categoryBits;
    filterA.groupIndex = groupIndex;
    filterA.maskBits = maskBits;
}
```

To understand how this works, check out the [Box2D manual chapter 6.2 (Filtering)](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082972).